# Form to sql table columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Alright so I want data entered in forms to go in certain columns as I have below, but it isn't working, maybe I haven't done it right?

[image]

html form

```
<form action="insert" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id" style="width: 40px;">
    <input type="text" name="item_ids" placeholder="item_ids" style="width: 70px;">
    <input type="text" name="catalog_name" placeholder="catalog_name" style="width: 100px;">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php file/action

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO catalog_items (id, page_id, item_ids, catalog_name, cost_credits, cost_pixels, cost_snow, amount, vip, achievement)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]',16,'$_POST[item_ids]','$_POST[catalog_name]',1000,0,0,1,0,0)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "added";

mysqli_close($con);
```

whats going wrong thats stopping the data from being inserted?

Comment: `action="insert.php"` instead of `action="insert"`?

Comment: I hope this isn't live; its vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: @Sean insert.php doesn't work, I just use insert

Comment: Is it returns 'added' or some 'Error: ...'?

Comment: Can you tell more about what is happening / not happening? Is it going to your `insert` page? Is it giving an error message? Does it say 'added', but it does not actually add to the database?

Comment: Sorry, it returns Error: Data truncated for column 'vip' at row 1
where there are ,1000,0,0,1,0,0) and not the $POST, i want them number to be the value for the rest of the columns so they dont enter it in

Comment: What is the data type for column `vip`?

Comment: @Sean now you mentioned type, I changed it from enum to int and it works now. thanks :)

Comment: `$_POST` data directly in the query? **DO NOT DO THIS**, especially when `mysqli` has the [`bind_param`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method that does this for you in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

You need this type of query kindly add others values and variables as you need

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$items = $_POST['item_ids'];
$catalog = $_POST['catalog_name'];

$sql="INSERT INTO `catalog_items` (`id`, `item_ids`, `catalog_name`, ect .....) VALUES('".$id."','".items."','".catalog."', ect .....)";
```